# Moving a UIImage's X-Coordinates With a Swipe Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a Swipe Gesture Recognizer which (obviously) recognizes every time you swipe (right).

Every time you swipe right, I want the `UIImage View`, **trumpImage** to move **X-Coordinate + 50**. But when I swipe, nothing happens.

Any suggestions? Here is the code that I have been playing with so far.

Thanks for the help!

```
@IBAction func swipeRight(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if (gameIsRunning == true) {

        var trumpX = trumpImage.frame.origin.x

        if gameIsRunning == true {

            trumpX += 50

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have the same if inside your first if statement which doesn't make sense at all.

Second you're assigning `trumpImage.frame.origin.x` to a variable and then adding 50 to that variable. You're not changing the image's frame.

To change the frame, modify your code like this:

```
@IBAction func swipeRight(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if (gameIsRunning == true) {
        let frame = trumpImage.frame
        trumpImage.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x + 50, y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are increasing var trumpX after two checks of the same variable gameIsRunning, you have to assign new frame to an image